# div блок не расширяется на 100% экрана

Tags: html, css

На моем сайте http://kelzin.kz в самом низу страницы есть `div` блок футер. У него стоит `width: 100%`, находится он непосредственно в `body`

Ничего его не стесняет, как по мне, но как видно слева и справа есть 2 зазора, которые я ни как не могу там убрать! `html` и `body` имеют 100% `width` и `height`, так же нулевой `padding` и `margin`. Понять не могу где тут косяк — при том как мы видим (!) шапка сайта растягивается как миленькая!

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с информацией на мете касательно топиков подобного содержания, на будущее пригодится. 
http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2653/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<div id="container">` по умолчанию 1280. Он и фиксируется ваш footer.

Answer (score 2):

Блок с ID `FOOTER` находится внутри контейнера `container`
Перенесите его ниже, после закрытия элемента контейнера.